# ORDER by two columns not working

Tags: mysql

I want to sort by two columns.Both are strings on is popularity another is createDT in MYSQL. popularity will have number and createDT has 25-05-2016 format.

Am trying the below query. But which ever i keep first i mean i i keep order by popularity ASC, createDT DESC. It is taking first column. I tried keeping STR_TO_DATE also. not working. i want it should check order by both.

```
SELECT
    id,
    productId,
    productJson
FROM
    product
WHERE
    subcategory = ?
ORDER BY
    STR_TO_DATE(createDt, '%d-%m-%Y') DESC,
    popularity ASC
```

Comment: Do you have an example output of that query? Maybe you expect another behaviour

Comment: I mean the products should display in the order using created date and popluarity.. if 5 products have same date nd popularity differs then it should see which product has less number that should come first

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expected result ? The query looks good.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    id,
    productId,
    productJson,
    popularity,
    createDt
FROM
    product
WHERE
    subcategory = ?
ORDER BY
    STR_TO_DATE(createDt, '%d-%m-%Y') DESC,
    popularity ASC;
```

It's worked for me.